# Magento Shopper Theme add to cart not working

Tags: magento

I'm using the Magento Shopper Theme (http://shopper.queldorei.com/).

When I add a product to cart, cart doesn't update and show the products added to cart. But if I refresh the page, then it shows the products added in the cart.

Does anybody have an idea of what to do to fix this?

Comment: The theme uses ajax for add to cart. Once you click add to basket, hover over the bag and you will see your item. The theme has been designed to wok this way purposely, if you do not want it to work this way, you need to change the add to basket links to be standard magento add to basket links. Look in the themes catalog phtml files and compare to magento's base catalog files and you should be able to see what they have changed and what you need to do in order to make it work the way you want it to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think you didn't understood my problem. Here is the demo link of theme: http://themeforest.net/item/shopper-magento-theme-responsive-retina-ready/full_screen_preview/3139960. Add any product to cart and see how the bag link on the top updates and shows the product added to cart. Now here is the link on which this functionality is not working http://www.wecartit.com. I need a solution so that my cart updates as soon as a product is added into it. This functionality was working fine a few days back. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't provide the link to your own implementation in the question so how could I have understood your exact issue? Use a debugger to debug the request and you can see there is an error occurring when you click the add to basket link. Have a look at error report 1015891621671 in /var/report which should give you something go on or post the error report back. The controller action causing the issue is http://www.wecartit.com/ajax/index/add so look for the addAction in the indexController for the AJAX module and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem. Use chromes debugger to debug ajax requests. Also, you are including jquery but it doesn't exist at the URL specified.

[image: The Request & Error Occuring When You Click Add To Basket Link]

Comment: Here is the error report link:

http://www.wecartit.com/misc/error%20report.txt

Kindly help me solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: You have already sent the response headers once and are trying to do it again. Without seeing all the code for the theme and project I can't tell you exactly how to fix it. Look at the following file: app/code/local/Excellence/Ajax/controllers/IndexController.php and find the addAction function. I suspect it returns the response as json and would need to do something like $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);. You need to ensure that no code is trying to return response data after you see this line. Use die() to debug the function a line at a time until you find where the problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check you have included more that 1 jquery files .

Comment: Which jquery file is duplicated? Can you tell me the name of the duplicated file and its path.